# How can I easily handle redirects by JSON in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, redirect

I have a directory on my web server called `/go/`. In practice, this would be used as `https://example.com/go/x` where `x` is a variable stored in a JSON file. The JSON file can be set up like so;

```
{
    "stackoverflow": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
    "apple":         "https://apple.com/",
    ...
}
```

I would like to, somehow, check if any of these variables check the `/go/x` and redirect them to their equivalent. In practice, it would be used like `https://example.com/go/stackoverflow` and it will redirect me to this site.

I don't want to add multiple HTML files in that directory and redirect from there, as I want to externally manage the JSON responses. That is irrelevant though.

I currently don't already have a solution, but was thinking of a JavaScript script that checks the JSON for any match. I don't know, however, how that script will get run because it never gets hit or called by anything. I already have the script that could get called, but don't know how to call it when `/go/x` is urgent:

```js
import "Paths.json" as Paths;
if (window.location.pathname == "/go/") {
    const Location = JSON.parse(Paths)[window.location.href];
    window.location.replace(Location);
}
```

**Conclusion**: I would like to redirect users to different pages depending on the variable `x` in `/go/x`. The redirects are stored in JSON. Every time `/go/` gets hit, I would like to run a JavaScript script to check on that variable and redirect the user to another page *without* adding different HTML files for each redirect and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure your web server to serve a html file, say `redirect.html` for `/go/*`. This preserves the pathname while handling all paths

You could then redirect the user based on the pathname.

Script in redirect.html:

```js
const data = //load data;
const redir = location.pathname.replace("/go/","");
location.href = data[redir];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can this also be done using a `.htaccess`?